# Private static files on AWS with django app

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gitlab-ci

I am running a django application and would like to host my static files (which includes my documentation with sphinx) on AWS. I configured everything and it works fine.

It only works though if my bucket has public permissions. I do not want my static files be accessible to the public though. Yet I think that static files must be public on AWS.

Is there any way of restricting the access to the bucket and still use it to serve my static files?

I know that I can restrict the traffic to certain IP addresses, but since I am running my app on Heroku I don't have a fixed IP but DNS.

I can't believe there is no way of hosting private static files. Or maybe do I need a different provider than AWS?

Help is highly appreciate, I am stuck with this since forever. Thanks so much in advance...

Comment: If you want to use static files as an asset to your django app , you need to have public  read permission to those files, write access should not be given.Why do you wanna restrict read access to the static files?

Comment: Rajan, thanks for you reply. I have a documentation which I want to put in this bucket, that shouldn't be accessible to the public. It's basically a html site which gets updated every time I push something to the master with Gitlab CI. So I wanted to have this documentation private while being able to update it from other repos than my site. Do you think this is possible somehow?

Comment: yes, you can definitely restrict access to s3 objects using multiple techniques.You can go through [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/secure-s3-resources/) resource for more details.You can write a bucket policy to restrict access to that particular object in your bucket.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think that the Heroku IP is relevant here. It's not Heroku that is reading your files, but the users' browser.

Comment: Thanks Rajan! Ok, so what you are saying is that I could restrict my access to certain folders in my AWS bucket for certain IAM users in which I could host my documentation?

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Well I thought I could restrict access on AWS that only I could access my docs from my network somehow....

Comment: I have done this in the past, so I know it's possible. Have you taken a look at [this solution](https://testdriven.io/blog/storing-django-static-and-media-files-on-amazon-s3/#private-media-files)? Maybe you could pass a privatemediastorage as your static storage? The only caveat will be that all your static files will be private and under an expiration time, but you could then theoretically do some sort of access control for certain files.

Comment: Thanks Nico! I checked it out. Was that the solution you implemented? If all my static files are private wouldn't it then be impossible to see the website with its css etc?

Comment: @Micromegas as you can see from the example shared by Nico, the static files in there are public (since anyone must be able to download the images, icons, css and js of your website), and the media files (uploaded files) are either public or private (two different storages defined). The private media files are only accessible with certain permissions and the Django app itself should also be a good citizen and only show the private media links to those that should have access.

Comment: @Micromegas I don't think it makes sense to have private static files at all. Please describe your use case in more detail (what do you mean by "html site"), how are these files served, are they served by django views, etc...

Comment: Thanks dirkgroten and sorry when I wasn't clear enough. Well I created a documentation with sphinx for Project A. My website should privately render this documentation so only authenticated users can access it. At the same time I want to use Gitlab CI to automatically deploy changes. So my idea was to push my changes from project A to the bucket and my website gets it through the static files and when I deploy the changes are there. is that a bad idea?

Comment: And is that doable with the recommended suggestions?

Comment: But sphinx documentation has multiple links (urls) and pages, how would you serve those? It's not like including static files in html pages served by django, so it doesn't have anything to do with static. AWS S3 cannot serve an html site if it's not public (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteEndpoints.html).

Comment: I thought I could do that when I just have the whole _build folder up there. But yes you are right, I think that was the wrong approach from the start

Comment: I have a little follow up question on the solution @Nico suggested: I am trying now (not with sphinx) to implement this solution with private and public media files. But my static files are now all private. Even though the static files should be in a different storage. Is it still necessary with this solution to create S3 presigned URLs? Maybe someone can help me out with this